# CIFilter (gausianBlurr) with Animator Creates Memory Leaks

Tags: macos, cocoa, memory-leaks, cifilter, animator

I ma trying to create a simple slide menu.

I created an `NSView` and Applied Gaussian Blurr to it's `CALayer`

//Menu initWithFrame method.

```
m_blur = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
[m_blur setDefaults];
[m_blur setValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:7] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
m_backgroundFiltersArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:m_blur];

- (void)setVisible:(BOOL)bVisible
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        if (!bVisible)
        {
            [self.layer setBackgroundFilters:nil];
            [self.layer.superlayer setBackgroundFilters:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.layer setBackgroundFilters:m_backgroundFiltersArray];
            //Also Update the Driver's Parameters here.
        }
    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

In my App main View I am calling the menu like this

In init with Frame

```
m_menuView = [[MenuView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(-fcMenuWidth, 0, fcMenuWidth, 446.0)];
[m_menuView setDelegate:self];
[self addSubview:m_menuView];


- (void)summonMenu
{
    if(!m_bMenuUp)
    {
        m_bMenuUp = YES;
        [m_menuView setVisible:YES];
        [[m_menuView animator] setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, fcMenuWidth, self.frame.size.height)];
    }
}
- (void)hideMenu
{
    if (m_bMenuUp)
    {
        m_bMenuUp = NO;
        [m_menuView cancelPopUpButtons];

        [[m_menuView animator] setFrame:NSMakeRect(-fcMenuWidth, 0, fcMenuWidth, self.frame.size.height)];
        [m_menuView setVisible:NO];
    }
}
```

However Each time I hide or summon the Menu 
I have some little memory leak.

I tried to profile it in Instruments -- it tells about `OpenGL` context 
That has about 768bytes leak each time.

I played around with functions
And discovered that when I am calling `m_menuView setFrame:` without the `.animator` property it all works fine and no leaks occurs.
Also if I disable `CIFilter` and use `animator` it works fine.

Can someone enlighten me how can I work this round please?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try putting your `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]` in the `@autoreleasepool`. I had a similar issue once and also did something along the lines of `[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:CGRectNull];` (it will be different for yours) when no longer wanting to retain the object.

Comment: @l'L'l Tried to put it in the `@autoreleasepool` - also completely removed the `setWantsDisplay` also tried `[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:CGRectNull];` still same leak :

Comment: How are you initializing the variable?

Comment: The one that's leaking (m_menuView?) - where do you define that before the alloc on it ... What makes you think it's leaking, and how are you profiling it? I'm not sure there's enough of your code to really determine the issue if there is one, since it looks ok.

Comment: @l'L'l I profiled it with instruments with leaks template.
Every time the `m_menuView` is animated I can see that `OpenGL context` is leaking in instruments.
Also I see the memory foot print is increasing.

It seems like there is something faulty in Drawing Code when it being animated.
However I am not overriding `drawRect` or any kind of manual rect drawing methods.

Comment: Maybe provide some of the leaks backtrace, or try the "Analyze" tool in Xcode also, it can help in addition to Profile. What type of object is m_menuView (a frame) ? ... It's a bit unclear. And you haven't shown how/where it's defined before `alloc`.

Comment: @l'L'l It's an `NSView` with nested layer that I applying `m_blurr` to it.
Added pictures to the Question